# Откуда взялось это слово - "тракт"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Какова этимология слова "тракт"?

Answer (score 1):

Первоначально - из латыни (tractus).

А затем спорно - из немецкого ли (Тrаkt) или польского (trakt).

Большая Советская Энциклопедия рассказывает:

[**ТРАКТ**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-13746.htm)

> (нем. Trakt, от лат. tractus, букв. - волочение, от traho - тащу),
>   улучшенная грунтовая дорога, соединяющая важные населенные пункты;
>   имела станции (постоялые дворы) и верстовые столбы. По тракту шли
>   регулярные перевозки пассажиров, грузов и почты (почтовые тракты с
>   почтовыми станциями). С 19 в. тракт с твердым покрытием называют
>   шоссе.

Большой толковый словарь даёт нам и второе значение слова:

[**ТРАКТ**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82&all=x) [нем. Trakt из лат.]

> 1. Устар. Большая наезженная дорога. Почтовый, торговый т. Московский т. Прямым трактом (прямым сообщением; тем же путём).
> 2. Спец. Совокупность средств для передачи, перемещения чего-л. Т. радиосвязи. Т. звукопередачи. Пищеварительный, желудочно-кишечный т.
>      (совокупность пищеварительных органов у животных и человека).

Ещё одна [уточнённая этимология слова "тракт"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82), но без указания на источник (не Макс Фасмер):

> Происходит от лат. tractus «тяга; протяжение», далее из trahere
>   «тянуть, тащить», далее из праиндоевр. *tragh- «тянуть, тащить».

Answer (score 0):

**ТРАКТ,**  [нем. Trakt из лат.] 1. **Устар.** Большая наезженная дорога. Почтовый, торговый т. Московский т. Прямым трактом (прямым сообщением; тем же путём). 2. Спец. Совокупность средств для передачи, перемещения чего-л. Т. радиосвязи. Т. звукопередачи. Пищеварительный, желудочно-кишечный т. (совокупность пищеварительных органов у животных и человека).

Уже подробно сказано, откуда слово взялось, **осталось уточнить ― когда**. Черных уверяет, что в русском языке оно появляется **в начале 18 века** (из западноевропейских языков), но вот Большой этимологический словарь (2013) указывает другую дату ― **15 век**, от польского из немецкого.

И непонятно, **когда и почему слово устарело** (может быть, в начале 19 века, когда появилось **шоссе** (от фр. chaussée ― дорога). Или специальный термин оттеснил дорогу-тракт в сторону, на обочину?